# How to move an image beneath the text using only css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move an image underneath the text. I tried (position: absolute) and moving the image with -px but I want the image to stay in the same place on the HTML but have it moved using only CSS. I am doing a mobile-first approach and because of the desktop design, the IMG has to stay at the same position in HTML. I also tried to moving the text but it just goes over the image or the padding and just doesn't work. It might be easier to explain by screenshots:

**The results I want to achieve:**

[image]

And my current results are:

[image]

And my current code is:

```css
img {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header id="titleHeader">
            <h1><span id="boot">Example</span>Text</h1> 
            <a class="navbutton" href="#navbar">Menu</a>
        </header>
        <section id="intromessage">
            <img alt="shoes" src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-h8hjw/products/927/images/735/WBHQ19-Retail-Product-OnWhite-Boots-M-1500x1425__00368.1599677007.475.500.png?c=2">
            <div>
              <h2>Example Text</h2>
              <p>
                example text, example text, example text<span> example text </span>example text
                <span>example text</span>
              </p>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: try [flex-direction: column-reverse](https://cssreference.io/property/flex-direction/)

Comment: And make sure to set display:flex on the #intromessage element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
<style>
   #intromessage{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column-reverse;
     }
</style>
```

Comment: This has worked but now the media query for desktop has changed. See the images: Before: https://i.imgur.com/MuOLsxR.png and now after: https://imgur.com/Zk99fec.

Comment: Add the style to the mobile media query you using and it wont effect the desktop.

Comment: nevermind I found out how to fix it, I just added flex-direction: row to media query for section

Answer (score 1):

A few options are avalaible.

- `transform:scale(x)` can be used

```css
#intromessage,
#intromessage>* {
  transform: scale(1, -1); /* value to add/remove via mediaquerie */
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="titleHeader">
  <h1><span id="boot">Example</span>Text</h1>
  <a class="navbutton" href="#navbar">Menu</a>
</header>
<section id="intromessage">
  <img alt="shoes" src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-h8hjw/products/927/images/735/WBHQ19-Retail-Product-OnWhite-Boots-M-1500x1425__00368.1599677007.475.500.png?c=2">
  <div>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
    <p>
      example text, example text, example text<span> example text </span>example text
      <span>example text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

- for older browser, `display:table` could be involved :

```css
#intromessage {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}

#intromessage>div {
  display: table-header-group;/* value to add/remove via mediaquerie */
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="titleHeader">
  <h1><span id="boot">Example</span>Text</h1>
  <a class="navbutton" href="#navbar">Menu</a>
</header>
<section id="intromessage">
  <img alt="shoes" src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-h8hjw/products/927/images/735/WBHQ19-Retail-Product-OnWhite-Boots-M-1500x1425__00368.1599677007.475.500.png?c=2">
  <div>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
    <p>
      example text, example text, example text<span> example text </span>example text
      <span>example text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

- flex is already answered but `order` can be used too :

```css
#intromessage {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;/* to be different from other answer */
}

#intromessage>div {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  order: 1;/* value to add/remove via mediaquerie */
}
```

```html
<header id="titleHeader">
  <h1><span id="boot">Example</span>Text</h1>
  <a class="navbutton" href="#navbar">Menu</a>
</header>
<section id="intromessage">
  <img alt="shoes" src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-h8hjw/products/927/images/735/WBHQ19-Retail-Product-OnWhite-Boots-M-1500x1425__00368.1599677007.475.500.png?c=2">
  <div>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
    <p>
      example text, example text, example text<span> example text </span>example text
      <span>example text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

- and the latest : `grid` can use  `order` too

```css
#intromessage {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  order: 1;/* value to add/remove via mediaquerie */
}
```

```html
<header id="titleHeader">
  <h1><span id="boot">Example</span>Text</h1>
  <a class="navbutton" href="#navbar">Menu</a>
</header>
<section id="intromessage">
  <img alt="shoes" src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-h8hjw/products/927/images/735/WBHQ19-Retail-Product-OnWhite-Boots-M-1500x1425__00368.1599677007.475.500.png?c=2">
  <div>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
    <p>
      example text, example text, example text<span> example text </span>example text
      <span>example text</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I never thought of using transform for this! This is extremely helpful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexbox for a responsive layout.

```
  #intromessage {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
```

Here is a good resource: [CSS Tricks - Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)